# Any way to deal with bitter taste from turbo yeast?

Tags: yeast, off-flavor, ginger-beer

I had some turbo yeast left over, and figured I'd try make a couple litres of ginger beer (sugar, grated ginger, a little lime juice) and elderflower wine (sugar, elderflowers, lemon juice and zest) with it. Both have ended up with the same extremely unpleasant bitter flavour. They're currently undrinkable. Is there anything I can do to get rid of it? Currently I'm aging the elderflower wine and hoping for the best; I started the ginger beer later and that's still fermenting.

Comment: I made a shed load of turbo wash.cleared with volcanic ash (cat litter).Then filtered.went well with some elder flower juice.☺

Answer (score 3):

Turbo yeast is very aggressive and consumes almost all sugars.

Bitter is most likley from an unbalance in sweet / bitter.

Add a non fermentable sugar like lactos to sweeten and counter the bitter to taste.

Comment: Since the two quite different mashes both gave a very similar taste, I suspect it's not just the lack of sweetness, but some by-product. If it were just dryness, I'd expect the ginger beer to just taste of ginger and alcohol, but there's something else.

Comment: @Max yeast can't form bittering acids naturally. Although scientists did just recently genieticly modify a yeast with mint and basil to produce bittering acids. If you post your recipes we can help you identify the source. Its pretty safe to say it's not from the yeast.

Comment: I suspect it might have been the yeast nutrient as @barking.pete suggests: in the one case it disappeared after a bit more fermentation, and in the other I pitched *a lot* of yeast, not realising that the turbo yeast was not just yeast.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO using turbo yeast for fermenting beer or other fizzy/alcoholic drinks is "less than optimal". It is not a yeast meant for directly fermenting drinks - it is a yeast mix meant for producing high alcohol content in a short time. The mix contains yeast and a lot of nutrient which can impart a biter flavour if not used up during fermentation. The idea of this yeast mix is to produce 24L of 20% alcohol mash *for distillation* (or to drink only if one has run out of methylated spirit :)

It may be advantageous to go buy some "normal" brewing yeast or, if all else fails, use bakers yeast. It is quite adequate for making ginger ale.